# In an add-in in Excel, written in C(++), how does one get the name of the function which called into the addin?

Tags: c++, c, excel-addins

The title says it all.  I have an add-in for Excel, written in
C++, and I would like to register several different functions in
Excel to call the same `extern "C"` function in my C++,
dispatching on the function called in Excel.  But to do so,
I need to be able to determine which Excel function called it.

EDIT:

Since it doesn't seem clear: we have a large plugin library for
Excel, written in C++.  We are extending it, and one of the
things we want to do it allow this library to support plugins
itself, possibly written in other languages.  (We use Python
a lot for higher level things, for example.)  When I load one of
these plugins, I get a *pointer* to the functions that I need to
register, along with information about their arguments, return
values, etc.  I need some way of registering these functions
with Excel, so that the Excel user can access them.  My basic
thought was that I would have a single function in my library,
which would forward to the desired function (typically a Python
function, so I'd marshall the Excel arguments into a Python
list, call the Python function using `PyObject_CallObject`, and
then marshall the return values back into an `xloper12` and
return it to Excel.  When registering the functions, the
`pxProcedure` string would always be the name of my marshalling
function.  The `pxTypeText` and the `pxFunctionText` would be
different each time.  What I need to do is to somehow obtain the
`pxFunctionText` which led Excel to call into my function, so
I can map it to the argument list (to know what types my actual
arguments are) and the address of the function that I actually
have to call (the `PyObject*`, in the case of Python).

For the moment, Grady Player's suggestion is about the only
thing which comes to mind; it would actually solve two problems
at once, since it would give me a named first argument for the
`va_args` part as well.  But it raises more questions than it
answers: how to I define a macro from the C++ code, for example?
I can't find any combination of available functions *in native
C++* that would allow it.

Comment: Something along the lines of tag-dispatching?

Comment: could you make a vbi macro that does the dispatching... like doThingA(args) -> doThing(a,args); I don't know the problem domain...

Comment: @Niall More or less.  The problem is to get the tag.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow then, do you control the source code, i.e. can you rebuild it?

Comment: @Niall We control it, but we want to make it more dynamic.  The "tag" should be the name with which the function was registered with in Excel, and this will only be determined at runtime, with several Excel functions ultimately calling a single function in C++, which dispatches on the name of the Excel function.